# Getting error in epoch_cost "operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (32,) (5,) (32,) " while applying minibatches in neural net

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning

I am doing this project in which i applied minibatches in neural network and calculating epoch cost:-

```
def model(X_train, Y_train, X_test, Y_test, learning_rate = 0.0001, num_epochs = 1500,
      minibatch_size = 32, print_cost = True):

ops.reset_default_graph()
tf.set_random_seed(1)
seed = 3
costs = []

(n_x, m) = X_train.shape
n_y = Y_train.shape[0]

#create placeholder
X, Y = create_placeholder(n_x, n_y)

# init parameter
parameters = init_parameter()

# forward prop
Z3 = forward_prop(X, parameters)

# compute cost
cost = compute_cost(Z3, Y)

# optimizer
optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate= learning_rate).minimize(cost)

# Initialize all variables
init = tf.global_variables_initializer()

with tf.Session() as sess:

    sess.run(init)

    for epoch in range(num_epochs):
        epoch_cost = 0
        num_minibatche = int(m/ minibatch_size)

        seed = seed + 1

        minibatches = random_mini_batches(X_train, Y_train, 
                                 minibatch_size, seed)

        for minibatch in minibatches:

            (minibatch_X, minibatch_Y) = minibatch
            _, minibatch_cost = sess.run([optimizer, cost], feed_dict 
                          = {X: minibatch_X, Y: minibatch_Y})


            epoch_cost += minibatch_cost / num_minibatche


        # Print the cost every epoch
        if print_cost == True and epoch % 100 == 0:
            print ("Cost after epoch " ,epoch, np.mean(epoch_cost))
        if print_cost == True and epoch % 5 == 0:
            costs.append(epoch_cost)


    # plot the cost
    plt.plot(np.squeeze(costs))
    plt.ylabel('cost')
    plt.xlabel('iterations (per tens)')
    plt.title("Learning rate =" + str(learning_rate))
    plt.show()

    # save the parameters
    parameters = sess.run(parameters)
    print ("Parameters have been trained!")

    # Calculate the correct predictions
    correct_prediction = tf.equal(tf.argmax(Z3), tf.argmax(Y))

    # Calculate accuracy on the test set
    accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_prediction, "float"))

    print ("Train Accuracy:", accuracy.eval({X: X_train, Y: Y_train}))
    print ("Test Accuracy:", accuracy.eval({X: X_test, Y: Y_test}))

    return parameters
```

SO when i run this code i am getting this error on line:-

---->epoch_cost += minibatch_cost / num_minibatche

---->ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (32,) (5,) (32,)

I took minibatche_size = 32 and number of training examples = 1381
But i am totally confused why i am getting this error.

Answer (score 0):

The code you've posted is missing a lot of parts, like the whole `model()` function, so it's difficult to debug. But based on just what we have, some things here that are supposed to be scalars are in fact, arrays.

`epoch_cost` starts out as a scalar zero with `epoch_cost = 0`. Then you add some value to it, then try to print `np.mean( epoch_cost )`. Why do you take the mean of a scalar? Looks like the code was different earlier, and the migration to a scalar `epoch_cost` was not successful.

It is easy to imagine that `minibatch_cost` is returned as an array from TensorFlow - one cost value for each member of the batch. In that case you would need to apply `np.mean()` right there, like

```
epoch_cost += np.mean( minibatch_cost ) / num_minibatche
```

Maybe even `num_minibatche` somehow became a vector. It comes from

```
num_minibatche = int(m/ minibatch_size)
```

and `minibatch_size` is supposedly 32, so that's all right. But `m` comes from

```
(n_x, m) = X_train.shape
```

and we know nothing of X_train. Maybe `m` somehow became a vector, and in turn `num_minibatche` too. You will need to print the value for `num_minibatche` once calculated and make sure it's what it's supposed to be.

Hope this helps. If you post the whole code, I can help you more.